# Magento: add icons to the menu-links in your Account-dashboard

Tags: css, magento, customization

Is it possible to add icons to all/some of the menu-links in your account-dashboard? Is there a node/style-attribute in the layout XML-file that should come with the addLink-action?

`<action method="addLink" translate="label" module="randomname"><name>randomname</name><path>randomname/index/credits</path><label>Credits</label></action>`

You have your default *Account Dashboard*, *Account Information*, *Addresses*, *My Orders*,... menu-items, but I added a new one; "Credits", and I want to make it "pop" out with an icon and/or another background-color. Couldn't figure out how to do it so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Ok, I've found out that there's no parameter to set a css class or id in the addLink() function:

```
public function addLink($name, $path, $label, $urlParams=array())
    {
        $this->_links[$name] = new Varien_Object(array(
            'name' => $name,
            'path' => $path,
            'label' => $label,
            'url' => $this->getUrl($path, $urlParams),
        ));
        return $this;
    }
```

Now you have two options to add icons to the links. 1. Overwrite the **Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation** Block Class within your own module and extend the addLink method or 2. you could set the css class/id via jQuery. Good Luck!

Comment: Crashes the whole site/shop. Blank page.

Comment: Found something other on the web, maybe this works: `<aParams>'class="top-link-about-us"'</aParams>` or `<aParams><class>my-class-name</class></aParams>`

Comment: Tried the following: <aParams> with 'class...' in it, or <class>, <liParams> with 'class...' or <class>. All efforts gave blank page, or  added the text in the <a> url.

Comment: Tried this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/me/viewthread/221951/#t306107 didn't work (blank page) Tried this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/201212/#t257005 didn't work also.

Comment: Ok, I've found out that there's no parameter to set a css class or id in the addLink() function: `public function addLink($name, $path, $label, $urlParams=array())`. Now you have to options to add icons to the links. 1. Overwrite the **Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation** Block Class within your own module and extend the addLink method or 2. you could set the css class/id via jQuery. Good Luck! Danny